# Netbeans Add method not implemented

Tags: netbeans

I'm running my java ee 7 application under netbeans 8.1 and glassfish,
There is a specific class which need restart the server after every any little change, and when try yo click apply code changes the netbeans tell me... The virtual machine does not support this operation: add method not implemented ...although there is no any method added

Answer (score 0):

It's a JVM error as you can read in [this issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262238)

You can enable hotswap in netbeans via DCEVM + [HotSwap Agent](http://hotswapagent.org).